# How to send 5000 mail from a gmail account programmatically?

Tags: email, gmail

I'm a researcher and i need to send 5000 mail to ask to the targets of my research to compile a survey. I own a gmail account bought to me by the university. How do i send this mail? I can write easily a simple script that send all the email but i'm afraid that sending so much messages could cause me problems leading to the block of my gmail account. I have not been able to understand what are the limits of a gmail account and how to realize a script able to do this without problem.

Comment: One question. Does this seems to be a programming question?

Comment: One answer. Reply with a programming answer. I'm supposing you can. If there a type of script or workaround to do what i ask i'd be glad to know.

Comment: Use an email service provider like Campaign Monitor or Mailchimp instead.

Comment: Campaign Monitor works like a charm. I think i'll use it. Thank you very much for the suggestione!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to not use Gmail for bulk mailouts for multiple reasons:

- **500 recipient limit:** Gmail has a 500 recipient limit for standard mailouts, and I believe 500 mailouts a day limit.[1]
- **CAN-SPAM Compliance:** Sending unsolicited emails may flag your account for spam, therefore compromising sending future emails from your account .

The easiest and best way to do this is either yourself using an SMTP server or using a service such as aWeber or ListWire etc to mail on your behalf for a nominal fee.

I would recommend doing a service if it's only a one off mailout, see this question for various services.
[Looking for bulk and transactional email-sending service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492425/looking-for-bulk-and-transactional-email-sending-service)

Additionally read up on CAN-SPAM compliance in order to ensure that if this is indeed unsolicited[2]. Your survey might be better off on a landing page explaining:

- **Who you are**
- **What you will do with their information**

[1] https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

[2] `emailmarketing.comm100.com/email-marketing-tutorial/can-spam-compliance.aspx`